# Getting tooltip to show up jquery tipTip

Tags: php, jquery, html, tooltip, tiptip

Hi guys I have been trying to insert a tooltip but I dont know what I am doing wrong..

I am including all the necessary files

```
 <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.tipTip.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.tipTip.minified.js"></script>
```

and using this script in the page too

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
$(".someClass").tipTip();
});
</script>
```

and this is how I implement it into html

```
 <a href="" class="someClass" title="This will show up in the TipTip popup.">Curabitur dolor eros</a>
```

what am I doing wrong?

here is the jsfiddle I think

http://jsfiddle.net/jFqFG/

Comment: can u reproduce this in jsfiddle

Comment: have you got any kind of error in firebug?? or do you have css file too??

Comment: Why are you including both the minified and non-minified versions? I believe you should only require one of these two files, since they are effectively the same thing. Also, is `jqeury.tipTip.js` (eu instead of ue) spelt correctly?

Comment: Oops yep it wasn't spelled correctly, changed now although it didnt fixed it, how would I reproduce this in jsfiddle?

Comment: minified and non-minified versions are logically same.Only difference is that minified file is the compressed form so requires less time to load.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jFqFG/ here is the jsfiddle?

Comment: Try this maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/nFPJ7/

I've admittedly copied in the TipTip code directly; your JS is underneath it.

Comment: If I edit your jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jFqFG/) by removing `jquery-1.7.2.js` from the Managed Resources panel, and then click Run, it seems to work for me (using Chrome). Please note the jsfiddle includes jQuery by default under the Choose Framework panel. Are those all the script references you're using? Or are there others on the page as well?

Comment: that is weird, you are right, I stopped including the jqeury-1.7.2 and now it suddenly works (both in jsfiddle and in the actual website) thanks guys

Comment: how do I put this to a solved topic? since people just commented and I can't really choose an answer

Comment: You can write your own answer and mark that as the solution I believe.

Comment: I have too low rep to answer my own question it seems, if anyone wants to answer it (take away the jqeury 1.7.2 include file) then I will choose it :) thanks to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue was related to including jQuery twice; once before the plugin was referenced, then once thereafter, thereby nuking the plugin when jQuery was re-initialized.

Removing the second reference to jQuery evidently resolved the issue, as discovered in the comments attached to the question.

Comment: Right also the working answer, I suppose this is earlier answered so it goes to you?

Comment: It goes to whoever you feel provided the best answer; in that way others who have a similar problem and find this page can hopefully solve it more easily ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There apparently seems to be some kind of a bug when including both jQuery and tiptip files. There is a link [here](http://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/tiptip/49-a-bug-with-including-jquerytiptipjs-when-using-both-jquery-and-prototype) which discusses the same and provides a patch to overcome the same.
I have not tested it . Those who can , please do and provide the results.

Comment: It seems to work fine when you include jQuery and the TipTip plugin files in the right order (placing TipTip last). Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFqFG/1/ - here we've included jQuery twice (once as the default framework, once manually in Manage Resources) yet it still seems to work. TipTip is in fact dependant on jQuery, as it's file name indicates.

Comment: The issue mentioned in the link provided specifically points to Prototype as part of the problem. Currently the question does not mention prototype; can the original poster confirm if Prototype is being used at all?